# Mongodb: Pull corresponding value from another collection

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two diff collections:

```
CollectionA
{
"_id" : 1.0,
"1234" : "GROUP"
}

{
"_id" : 2.0,
"2345" : "SUBGROUP"
}


CollectionB
{
"_id" : 1.0,
"config" : "1234",
"description" : "DCS"
}


{
"_id" : 2.0,
"config" : "2345",
"description" : "BCS"
}
```

I was expecting the below output when i write a find query by joining the two collections. Can we able to get the requested output by using $lookup function?

```
{
"_id" : 1.0,
"config" : "GROUP",
"description" : "DCS",
}


{
"_id" : 2.0,
"config" : "SUBGROUP",
"description" : "BCS",
}
```

Comment: Add the query that you are using to aggregate.

Comment: I have been written the below collection:                                         db.collection2.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "collection1",
          localField: "config",
          foreignField: "1234",
          as: "result"
        }
   }
]
)                 And the result is(which is not correct): /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "config" : "1234",
    "description" : "DCS",
    "result" : []
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2.0,
    "config" : "2345",
    "description" : "BCS",
    "result" : []
}

Comment: are you allowed to change your structure ?

Comment: Yes, the structure can be changed, but i was expecting the same output as i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your query like this:

```
db.getCollection('a').aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'b',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'data'
    }
},
{
    $unwind: '$data'
},
{
    $project: {
        config: '$1234', //In your schema you may have the same key instead of 1234 and 2345
        description: '$data.description'
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: Assume that the _id was auto generated, so that it will not matched in any case. Then how can i map between local and foreign field ? Its not mandatory to use only the aggregation framework, any other way also acceptable.

Comment: You can take any key instead of _id but remember that should be the common key value pair in both collection.

Comment: Thank you @Neel Rathod for your great help!!